# How to extend theme of draft-js-emoji-plugin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I need to extend only several CSS rules in [draft-js-emoji-plugin](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins).

Documented way is to pass `theme` object to configuration:

```
const theme = {
  emojiSelectButton: 'someclassname'
};
const emojiPlugin = createEmojiPlugin({theme});
```

Unfortunately, this overwrites entire theme classnames instead of adding single one. Based on comments in the code this behavior is by design:

```
// Styles are overwritten instead of merged as merging causes a lot of confusion.
//
// Why? Because when merging a developer needs to know all of the underlying
// styles which needs a deep dive into the code. Merging also makes it prone to
// errors when upgrading as basically every styling change would become a major
// breaking change. 1px of an increased padding can break a whole layout.
```

[In related issue](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/issues/786) developers suggested to import `draft-js-emoji-plugin/lib/plugin.css` and extend it in code. Anyway, each classname in this file has suffixes (CSS modules) and they might be changed so it's reliable.

I don't know how can I apply several fixes without coping entire theme.

Answer (score 4):

a better method would be to import {defaultTheme} from 'draft-js-emoji-plugin' and then extend it as below:

```
import emojiPlugin, { defaultTheme } from 'draft-js-emoji-plugin';

// say i need to extend the emojiSelectPopover's css then.

defaultTheme.emojiSelectPopover = defaultTheme.emojiSelectPopover + " own-class"

// own class is a class with your required enhanced css. this helps in preserving the old css.

const emojiPlugin  = createEmojiPlugin({
    theme : defaultTheme
})
```

and hence use the plugin as you like.

Comment: Remember to have a " " (empty space) before adding your own classes. Otherwise, it'll overwrite what's already there

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to have such flexibility, but it really is a pain to rewrite all classes.
What I did was to extract all class names to an object, and with `styled-components`, interpolated the classNames to the css definition. This way you can extend whatever you want, without worrying about styling a suffixed class (and it changing when they bump a version)
In this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Sauloxd/284b1f90b715e962cff8a79f66686a56) I've just copied all styles in v2.1.1 of `draft-js-emoji-plugin`

```
const theme = {
  emoji: 'my-emoji',
  emojiSuggestions: 'my-emojiSuggestions',
  emojiSuggestionsEntry: 'my-emojiSuggestionsEntry',
  // ...
  emojiSelect: 'emojiSelect',
  emojiSelectButton: 'emojiSelectButton',
  emojiSelectButtonPressed: 'emojiSelectButtonPressed',
}

const StyledEmojiSelectWrapper = styled.div`
  .${theme.emojiSelect} {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  .${theme.emojiSelectButton}, .${theme.emojiSelectButtonPressed} {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #888;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .${theme.emojiSelectButton}:focus, .${theme.emojiSelectButtonPressed}:focus {
    outline: 0;
    /* reset for :focus */
  }
  // ...
`

export const GlobalStyleForEmojiSelect = createGlobalStyle`
  .${theme.emoji} {
    background-position: center;
    //...
  }

export default (props) => (
  <StyledEmojiSelectWrapper>
    <GlobalStyleForEmojiSelect />
    <EmojiSelect /> // lib button component
  </StyledEmojiSelectWrapper>
)
```